# To invert colours from black to white in opencv python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, image-manipulation

I have a condition where I want to detect white line incase of black background and black line incase of white background. I used bitwise_not operation something like this:

```
cv2.bitwise_not(mask_black)
```

It is working perfectly until and unless i give a condition like this:

```
if mask_black == cv2.bitwise_not(mask_black):
```

I get an error

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I am having doubts about using conditions where if black background occurs white line is to be detected and if white background occurs black line is to be detected

```
mask_black = cv2.inRange(hsv, low_black, high_black)
mask_not=cv2.bitwise_not(mask_black)

if mask_black==cv2.bitwise_and(mask_black, mask_not):
    body 
else:
    body
```

This is returning the above error

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The idea is to check the background for white pixels with `cv2.countNonZero()`. We set a threshold, say 50%. If more than 50% of the background is white pixels then it means we are looking for the black line. Similarly, if  the majority of the background is black then we are looking for the white line.

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png', 0)
w, h = image.shape[:2]

if cv2.countNonZero(image) > ((w*h)//2):
    # Detect black line
    ...
else:
    # Detect white line
    ...
```

---

To invert an image, you can do this

```
invert = cv2.bitwise_not(image) # OR
#invert = 255 - image
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Actually I am using a Pi Camera to live stream and find the contours, so my resolution is set to 100,100. So I used 100,100 as w,h. If I am using the above code, I am getting the following error ```too many values to unpack``` or ``` error:(-215) cn ==1 in function countNonZero```

Comment: Don't use the code directly, use the main idea of the code. The main idea is to determine the amount of white pixels in the image, then based on the amount, check for white or black lines. Also make sure that you're passing a grayscale image (only 1-channel) to `cv2.countNonZero()`. Since you're using Pi Camera, convert the image to grayscale before putting it into the function `gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)`

Comment: I continued as you said, but AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'..  Maybe this error is due to live video capture

Comment: That error is due to incorrect/invalid captured frame. Ensure that the `status` code is valid

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion,  the gray scale display is working now but the whole screen is being displayed as contour rather than only white or black, any suggestions for that?

Comment: That's out of the scope of this post, you may want to open a new question for that

Answer (score 8):

```
invert = cv2.bitwise_not(image)
```

This is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cv2.bitwise_and(mask_black, mask_not)` where `mask_not` is `cv2.bitwise_not(mask_black)`

Comment: getting the same error  ```if cv2.bitwise_and(mask_black, mask_not) :
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()```