# MNIST trained network tested with my own samples

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I trained a Dense Neural Network with MNIST dataset in order to classify 28x28 images of numbers. Now I was trying to make it work with my own samples (I draw the image of a "7" in paint and I transformed it into an array) but the results are really poor.

```py
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = mnist.load_data()

from tensorflow.keras import models
from tensorflow.keras import layers

network = models.Sequential()
network.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(28*28,)))
network.add(layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

network.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])


train_images = train_images.reshape((60000,28*28))
train_images = train_images.astype('float32') / 255

test_images = test_images.reshape((10000, 28*28))
test_images = test_images.astype('float32') / 255

from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical

train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)

network.fit(train_images,train_labels,epochs=20,batch_size=512,validation_split=0.2)
print(network.evaluate(test_images,test_labels))


#-DEMO-----------------------------------------------------------------
from PIL import Image
import PIL.ImageOps
import os

direccio = 'C:/Users/marcc/OneDrive/Escritorio'
os.chdir(direccio)

myImage = Image.open("Image.PNG").convert('L')
myImage = PIL.ImageOps.invert(myImage)
myImage = myImage.resize((28,28))
myImage.show()

#transforming my image into an array (THE PROBLEM MUST BE HERE)
import numpy as np
myImage_array = np.array(myImage)
myImage_array = myImage_array.reshape((28*28))
myImage_array = myImage_array.astype('float32') / 255
myImage_array=myImage_array.reshape(1,784)
print(myImage_array.shape)


print(network.predict(myImage_array))
```

The code until DEMO is made by François Chollet. I only made the last part which is the implementation of my own image.

The results that I get after testing it with the image of a seven are:

```
[[6.9165975e-03 3.0256975e-03 4.9591944e-01 4.8350231e-03 5.6093242e-03
  8.6059235e-03 4.5295963e-01 8.3720963e-04 2.1008164e-02 2.8301307e-04]]
```

As you can see the results are really bad (the seventh position should have the highest probability)

If I plot an image of MNIST using the code:

```
digit = train_images[4]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(digit, cmap=plt.cm.binary)
plt.show()
```

It looks like:
[MNIST image of a 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBUHk.png)

If I do the same with my image:
[My Image of a 7 (after being transformed to an array)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ljEL.png)

Comment: Is this taken from a Github Repo?

Comment: No the first part is taken from the book Deep Learning with Python of François Chollet. I put it here because I think it's interesting to compare the way he implements the images and the way that I do.

Comment: Questions like these are difficult to debug, but you'll hopefully find more help on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ than here.

Comment: I have to say that I plotted an image of his dataset and I plotted mine after being vectorized and both look the same. So I don't understant why it's not working.

Comment: @Luke Thank you! I didn't know that existed

Comment: Anytime! On second thoughts consider adding more details to this question.

Comment: It might be because of the background color. In paint app, the default background color is white and in MNIST data, the background is black. Model is confused because it has never seen white background images. My suggestion for you is to invert the color of MNIST data. Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58142214/to-invert-colours-from-black-to-white-in-opencv-python) code. And train your model with both black and white background images, so that your model can become more robust.

Comment: @AdarshWase thank you, but I already invert my image using PIL.ImageOps.invert and as you can see in the plots both look very similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything is OK, the problem that I had is that in my region seven is normally written using another line (I really thought it was more extended).
Because I am using a Dense Network, it doesn't interpretate the shapes of numbers but the disposition of the pixels so a little modification on how the number is written may have really bad consequences in this simplistic model.

[7 written normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPTD2.png)

As Αpostolos-Valiakos said I really had to try different numbers. But I really thought that it was a problem of how my image is converted to an array. Thanks to everyone for their help

Answer (score 0):

The result you are getting is the distribution on the probability your sample to belong in each class. if you see the result

```
[[6.9165975e-03 3.0256975e-03 4.9591944e-01 4.8350231e-03 5.6093242e-03
8.6059235e-03 4.5295963e-01 8.3720963e-04 2.1008164e-02 2.8301307e-04]]
```

you see that there are 10 probabilities your sample to belong in the first class (no 1) in the second class (no 2) etc etc

if you look carefully your output, you will see that the highest propability is in the 7th place so the model classifies your sample as a number 7

if you want your output to be the number of the class you can try something like this

```
CATEGORIES = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"]

prediction = model.predict('your_sample')
max = (prediction.max(0))
result = (np.where(prediction == max))
print(CATEGORIES[result])
```

Comment: I tried tried the model with the training image shown above (it's a 9) and the result was that the last position of the probabilities vector was 9.9999261e-01. This proofs that the vector of probabilities associates each position with the numbers [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].

Comment: What I am saying is that I understand the Output that is giving me but it's not correct because the probabilities that are given aren't as expected.

Comment: What is the model evaluation accuracy? I'm asking cause if the model can classify easily the already known samples but it cannot classify unknown samples maybe there is an overfitting issue

Comment: The result is [0.07581456750631332, 0.9804999828338623].

Comment: if you try another number than the 7, whats the result?