# Training MNIST by loading my own img (with label of answer, load img 6 tell AI is 6)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have read through the following discussion (not saying how to load pic to MNIST database)
[MNIST trained network tested with my own samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69625822/mnist-trained-network-tested-with-my-own-samples)

I also planning to train my own mnist by input img, but most of the tutorial doen't teach how to load our personal img (with answer, teach AI to reconize)

**such as load all img "5" image into MNIST database, and teach them that number 5**

how can we do so?

the following .py script is training by MNIST own database (*credit by student_DC*), then reconize, but accuracy result is not ideal (about 10%), so I come up training my samply img too, before doing the MNIST

**but if I store the img on local file how to load them to MNIST model to train?**

- script after trained (both train and test from MNIST img databse) can load my own img to pridict

```
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PIL
from PIL import Image
(train_images,train_labels),(test_images,test_labels) = mnist.load_data()
train_images.shape
len(train_labels)
train_labels
test_images.shape
len(test_labels)
test_labels


from keras import models
from keras import layers
network = models.Sequential()
network.add(layers.Dense(512,activation='relu',input_shape=(28*28,)))
network.add(layers.Dense(10,activation='softmax'))


network.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
                loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                metrics=['accuracy'])


train_images = train_images.reshape((60000,28*28))
train_images = train_images.astype('float32')/255
test_images = test_images.reshape((10000,28*28))
test_images = test_images.astype('float32')/255

from keras.utils import to_categorical

train_labels = to_categorical(train_labels)
test_labels = to_categorical(test_labels)

network.fit(train_images,train_labels,epochs= 3 ,batch_size=128)


test_loss , test_acc = network.evaluate(test_images,test_labels)
print('test_acc:',test_acc)



network.save('m_lenet.h5')


#########

import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

model = load_model('/content/m_lenet.h5')

picPath = '/content/02_a.png'
img = Image.open(picPath)


reIm = img.resize((28,28),Image.ANTIALIAS)

plt.imshow(reIm)
plt.savefig('/content/result.png')

im1 = np.array(reIm.convert("L"))



im1 = im1.reshape((1,28*28))


im1 = im1.astype('float32')/255


#　predict = model.predict_classes(im1)


predict_x=model.predict(im1) 
classes_x=np.argmax(predict_x,axis=1)

print ("---------------------------------")

print ('predict as：')
print (predict_x)

print ("")
print ("")

print ('predict number as：')
print (classes_x)
print ("---------------------------------")
print ("Original img : ")
```

the sample img screenshot: [image: the sample img screenshot]

---

- by export suggestion:

> to pass img to  `model.fit` ,
> that mine `network.fit(train_images,train_labels,epochs= 3 ,batch_size=128)` and let AI train my img logically can solve the problem

I am stocking on how to create an array of train images and an array of corresponding labels for now, I search online don't get similar tutorial (with topic: *Training MNIST by loading my own img* )

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking. You seem to be successfully loading your image using `Image.open(picPath)` and using the model to predict the number in the image by calling `model.predict(im1)`. If you want to train the model using your own dataset, then you have to read all the images from your local space and pass it to the `model.fit` function.

Comment: yeah, for now I can let original MNIST predict my pic `(loading for testing works fine)` but accuracy result is about 10% ; that  need to know how to  `(loading img for training)` is my main purpose for now

Comment: hi @Ladislav Ondriscan , can you elaborate `passing img to model.fit` a little more, I want to know how to do so, thanks

Comment: your example already shows the usage of `model.fit`. You need an array of train images and an array of corresponding labels. How you read the images from your local disk is up to you. For convenience, you can use `tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory` to load your dataset. See the documentation for specific usage.

Comment: the `model.fit` ,  you mean `network.fit(train_images,train_labels,epochs= 3 ,batch_size=128)` ?  I do stocking on how to create **an array of train images and an array of corresponding labels**

Comment: Yes, you are correct. That's what I mean. The loading of the images and labels can be done by the function I mentioned in the last comment, or you can do that yourself by reading the images one by one.

Comment: I still don't know how to come up a code for that, could you give me a hand, if you post as answer, I can mark as solve for this

Answer (score 0):

cridet by this site, seems this is what you what for loading your own img to train
https://blog.tanka.la/2018/10/28/build-the-mnist-model-with-your-own-handwritten-digits-using-tensorflow-keras-and-python/

```
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Dropout
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.convolutional import Conv2D
from keras.layers.convolutional import MaxPooling2D
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.utils import np_utils
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load data
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()


# Reshaping to format which CNN expects (batch, height, width, channels)
X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], 1).astype('float32')
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], X_test.shape[2], 1).astype('float32')


# To load images to features and labels
def load_images_to_data(image_label, image_directory, features_data, label_data):
    list_of_files = os.listdir(image_directory)
    for file in list_of_files:
        image_file_name = os.path.join(image_directory, file)
        if ".png" in image_file_name:
            img = Image.open(image_file_name).convert("L")
            img = np.resize(img, (28,28,1))
            im2arr = np.array(img)
            im2arr = im2arr.reshape(1,28,28,1)
            features_data = np.append(features_data, im2arr, axis=0)
            label_data = np.append(label_data, [image_label], axis=0)
    return features_data, label_data


# Load your own images to training and test data
X_train, y_train = load_images_to_data('1', '/content/01', X_train, y_train)
X_test, y_test = load_images_to_data('1', '/content/01', X_test, y_test)

# normalize inputs from 0-255 to 0-1
X_train/=255
X_test/=255


# one hot encode
number_of_classes = 10
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, number_of_classes)
y_test = np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, number_of_classes)

# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (5, 5), input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(number_of_classes, activation='softmax'))

# Compile model
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, validation_data=(X_test, y_test), epochs=1, batch_size=200)


img = Image.open('/content/01/userlmn_01.png').convert("L")
plt.imshow(img)
img = np.resize(img, (28,28,1))

im2arr = np.array(img)
im2arr = im2arr.reshape(1,28,28,1)


# y_pred = model.predict_classes(im2arr)

predict_x=model.predict(im2arr) 
classes_x=np.argmax(predict_x,axis=1)

print(classes_x)
```